# C enum tags before and after list - type or var name?

Tags: c, enums

I see a lot of occasions (googling) where enums are declared as follows:

`enum enum_tag {a = 0, b, c, d} tag_again;`

`enum enum_tag {a = 0, b, c, d};`

or

`enum {a = 0, b, c, d} tag_again;`

Some times it seems like enum_tag is the type and tag_again is a variable name, but if enum_tag is not present tag_again seems to sometimes be used as either.. which is it?

If I were to code
`enum {a = 0, b, c, d} tag_again;`
Is tag_again an enum type or variable of a nameless enum type??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Continued my googling and MSDN gave me the answer: [MSDN C Enum Declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/c-enumeration-declarations)

`enum enum_tag {a = 0, b, c, d} tag_again;` defines an enum type enum_tag and declares a variable of that type: tag_again.

`enum enum_tag {a = 0, b, c, d};` defines an enum type of enum_tag

and

`enum {a = 0, b, c, d} tag_again;` declares a variable tag_again of a nameless enum type (as I thought)

Comment: howerever if typedef'ing the enum it seems that tag_again is the type, enum_tag is optional but if present must be the same as tag_again...